# Fscanf scanning incorrect information

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I'm a student tryig to print 6 lines I have inserted into a txt document called `test.txt`

The test file is simple plain text in a `.txt` with the following text, all on its own line:

```
Nikolaj
Ljorring
m
20
182
200
```

However, I need to put the loaded data into a struct which look likes this:

```
struct profile_info
{
char first_name[30];
char last_name[30];
char gender;
int age;
int height;
double weight;
};
```

And a loader / printing function that looks like so:

```
void user_profile_loader(struct profile_info user_profile)
{
FILE *file_pointer;
file_pointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", &user_profile.first_name);

fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", user_profile.last_name);

fscanf(file_pointer, "%c", &(user_profile.gender));

fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.age));

fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.height));

fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.weight));

printf("%s \n%s \n€c \n%d \n%d \n%lf", &user_profile.first_name, &user_profile.last_name,
user_profile.gender, user_profile.age, user_profile.height, user_profile.weight);

fclose(file_pointer);
}
```

However, my output looks like so:

```
Nikolaj
Ljorring
(wierd C with a line beneath it)c [So a wierd C followed by a normal lowercase c]
10
5
0.000000
```

Comment: How about `fscanf(file_pointer, " %c", &(user_profile.gender));`

Comment: and, `fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", user_profile.first_name);` should suffice

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the ekstra & was a stray from a previous try, fixed it :-)

as for white space in front of the `%c`, didn't fix it

Comment: regarding this line: `void user_profile_loader(struct profile_info user_profile)`,  passing the whole array is (almost) always a bad idea.  Much better to pass a pointer to the array.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the format strings: `"%s"` will not input the <newline> characters.  Therefore, the <newline> chars are still in the input buffer when the second call to `fscanf()` is made.   the `"%c"` will input a <newline> char.   In general, the %s and %c input/convert specifiers need to be prefixed in the format string with a space so any left over 'white space' is consumed.  Suggest `" %s"` and `" %c"`.  Note: always check the returned value from `fscanf()` (which in the posted code should always be `1`) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.weight));` will fail to perform properly because `.weight` is a `double` not an `int`.  suggest: `fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf", &(user_profile.weight));`

Comment: @user3629249, im passing the struct as i need to be able to enter the loaded information into the struct :-)
as i was also told in the selected answer i will be sure to make checks when getting input to make sure the opperation was succesfull, would you recommend doing this at every input throughout a program?

lastly the `%d ` to `%lf` was also mentioned in the answer, thanks for noticing though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", &user_profile.first_name);
                           ^ no need of & here
```

And here -

```
fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.weight));
```

You use `%d` to read a `double` value .You pass wrong argument it invokes *UB* .Use `%lf` here.

In your `printf` -

```
printf("%s \n%s \n€c \n%d \n%d \n%lf", &user_profile.first_name, 
 &user_profile.last_name,user_profile.gender, user_profile.age, user_profile.height, user_profile.weight);
```

What is `\n€c` ? You should use specifier `%c` .

**Note**- You should check return of `fopen` and `fscanf` .

Comment: The return value should be checked, too, but there's only so much we can repeat "if you had read the manual you would have noticed this and this and this" at people before it gets well and truly old... :(

Comment: @Seb Yeah , but  basically it wont be useless  even though. May help in some cases .  Though just mentioned in note , OP may or may not refer to it :-)

Comment: Im so sorry to have wasted you guys time, the € insetad of % was what caused the error, simply checking better for mistakes like this would've solved it, sorry again :-)

2nd Why should i  check return values for `fopen` and `fscanf` I'm pretty new to the subject so i don't see the benefit from this? :-)

Comment: @NikolajLjørring  It is better to handle in case these function fails

Comment: @ameyCU, hmmm, i don't see how that would have changed anyting here, but i will be sure to keep it in mind in the future :-)

Comment: @Dream_Reaper Suppose you tell `scanf` to read some integer data, and the user enters "TROLOLOLOL" instead... What is `scanf` to do with that?

Comment: there are a number of reasons to check the returned value from calls to system functions.   The most obvious is that such calls can fail.  This axiom will serve you well in programming:  "Never trust the user to input valid values."